# What is the "status" parameter in the exit_group(int status) linux call?

Tags: c, linux, process

The docs don't really say what `status` is.

What exactly is `status`?

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/exit_group.2.html

Comment: The same as the `status` parameter to `exit()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [exit(3) man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html):

> The C standard specifies two constants, `EXIT_SUCCESS` and
>   `EXIT_FAILURE`, that may be passed to exit() to indicate successful or
>   unsuccessful termination, respectively.

which is mentioned on the group_exit page you referred to. I think it is a typo that it is equivalent to `exit(2)` because there is no exit(2), only exit(3) in the standard library. I've confirmed this by reading the stdlib6 source code.

Since `group_exit(2)` is claimed equivalent to `exit` that means `status` has two defined values and all the rest (up to 255) are up to your definition. The rule still holds though, anything but EXIT_SUCCESS represents a failure of the program.

Answer (score 1):

status is the exit status of the program. For example:

```
$ ls a.txt
ls: cannot access a.txt: No such file or directory
$ echo $?
2
$
```

In the above output, exit status of ls is 2. Likewise, you should specify the status. It depends upon the logic you implemented.
If the exit status is set to 0, it shows that your program exits normally. Otherwise it exits abnormally.